# Слишком много параметров для функции оператора << ( с++)

Tags: c++, потоки-данных, перегрузка-операторов

Помогите пожалуйста с данным вопросом:
мне нужно вывести значение `a.summ`. Через поток `cout<<` не выводится. Решил сделать перегрузку потока `<<`. Написал следующий код и выводит ошибку: слишком много параметров для ф-ии оператора. С чем это может быть связано? спасибо

```
// num1.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct dz
{
    int summa;
    int dayz;
};

class weeknd
{
private:
    dz a, b, c;
    unsigned int n;
public:
    weeknd();
    weeknd(int , int , int , int);
    void set();
    void set(ifstream &);
    int count();

    ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &os, const weeknd &c) {
        os << "(" << c.real << ", " << c.imaginary << ")";
        return os;
    }
};

int sum(int x, int y, int z)
{
    return z + y + z;
}

weeknd::weeknd()
{
    a.summa = 1; a.dayz = 1;
    b.summa = 1; b.dayz = 7;
    c.summa = 1; c.dayz = 28;
}

weeknd::weeknd(int x, int y, int z, int k)
{
    a.summa = x; a.dayz = 1;
    b.summa = y; b.dayz = 7;
    c.summa = z; c.dayz = 28;
    n = k;
}

void weeknd::set()
{
    cout << "enter value for 1, 7 or 28 days: ";
    int x, y, z, k;
    cin >> x >> y >> z >> k;
    a.summa = x; b.summa = y; c.summa = z; n = k;
}

void weeknd::set(ifstream& f)
{
    if (!f) exit(-1);
    f >> weeknd::a.summa >> b.summa >> c.summa >> n;
}

int weeknd :: count()
{
    int array[3] = { a.summa, b.summa, c.summa };
    int min;
    for (int i(0); i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j(0); j < 3; j++)
        {
            for (int k(0); k < 3; k++)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    weeknd vary;

    cout << vary;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что такое  c.real и c.imaginary ?

Answer (score 4):

- Функция count() должна возвращать int, у тебя void
- Проверь функцию count() - есть ошибки
- Функция перегрузки оператора должна быть объявлена, как friend - у
  тебя просто кусок кода
- Ошибка по перегрузки оператора:

  ```
  ostream& operator <<(std::ostream &os, const weeknd &c) {
  os << "(" << c.real << ", " << c.imaginary << ")";
  return os;
  }
  ```

Где в твоем классе поля real и imaginary??? Чтобы твоя перегрузка работала, сделать хотя бы так:

```
class weeknd
{
private:
dz a, b, c;
unsigned int n;
int real;
int imaginary;
...
```

Comment: Функция weeknd()???

Comment: @Sublihim, функция count(). Исправился

Comment: ну, совсем другое дело )

Answer (score 4):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы объявили оператор `<<` как *член класса*. Дело в том, что все функции, объявленные как нестатический член класса, неявно получают еще один параметр - `this`. А записать в C++ оператор `<<` с тремя операндами - это уже чересчур... :)

Вынесите его за пределы класса `weeknd`, и данная ошибка пропадет :)

Про остальные вы не спрашиваете, так что я о них ничего и не пишу...